# Sum of integers in a string

Tags: javascript, loops

Here's my code:

```js
function sumDigits(num) {

  var string = num.toString();
  var result = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] === '-') {
      var negative = Number(string[i + 1]) * -1
      result = result + negative
    } else {
      result = result + Number(string[i])
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(sumDigits('-316'))
```

When I add -316 as an argument, my output is 7.  Why is it not taking -3 into the equation?  As an FYI, I am still new to coding, and not sure this is even the correct route to take.  All input is appreciated.

Comment: console.log() is your friend. You will see you forget to bump up one when you read the negative.

Comment: _"I am still new to coding"_ - Then make your life now and in the future easier and always indent your code properly.

Comment: The first iteration subtracts 3, the next one adds 3, completely undoing the previous one's subtraction, so you get the sum of digits excluding the first one if your number is negative.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to debug, console.log and debugger are your friend.

```js
function sumDigits(num) {

  var string = num.toString();
  var result = 0;
  console.log("my string:", string);

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    console.log("in loop", i, string[i]);
    if (string[i] === '-') {
      var negative = Number(string[i + 1]) * -1
      console.log("in if ", result, "+", negative);
      result = result + negative
      console.log("updated result", result);
    } else {
      console.log("in else ", result, "+", Number(string[i]));
      result = result + Number(string[i])
      console.log("updated result", result);      
    }
  }
  console.log("final result", result);
  return result;

}

sumDigits(-317);
```

Looking at the results you can see you find a negative and you get the next number. On the next iteration you read that same number again. So `-3 + 3` is zero. So you cancel it out. You need to skip your loop ahead by one.

```js
function sumDigits(num) {

  var string = num.toString();
  var result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] === '-') {
      var negative = Number(string[i + 1]) * -1
      result = result + negative
      // bump i
      i++;
    } else {
      result = result + Number(string[i])
    }
  }
  return result;

}

console.log(sumDigits(-317));
```

Answer (score 0):

- I am checking whether the number is greater than 0 or less than zero.
- Then if the number is less than zero, then I am merging the first element of array which will be (`-digit`) `digits[0] = digits[0] + digits[1];`.
  -then I am removing 2nd element from `digits` array.  `digits.splice(1, 1);`
- And At the end I am lopping through all the digits using `forEach` loop and returning total of the dum digits to `total`.

```js
const digitsSum = (number) => {

  let total = 0;
  if (number < 0) {
    let digits = number.toString().split('');
    digits[0] = digits[0] + digits[1];
    digits.splice(1, 1);
    digits.forEach(digit => total += parseInt(digit));
    console.log(total);
    return total;
  } else {
    let digits = number.toString().split('');
    digits.forEach(digit => total += parseInt(digit));
    console.log(total);
    return total;
  }
}

function calculateDigitSumLogic(number) {

}
digitsSum(-1203);
digitsSum(1203);
digitsSum(-201);
```

Comment: Okay I will change my answer

Comment: I just misunderstand the question now you can see I have changed the logics

Comment: Most of the `if` and `else` branch do the same, with the only difference being that the `if` branch also modifies the array

Comment: Okay so , It's okay if I do not check number and directly split it and then at the end I can see if the first element of array is negative or not and based upon than I can implement the logic?